# BASH base conversion from decimal to hex

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, hex

In Bash, how does one do base conversion from decimal *to* another base, especially hex.  It seems easy to go the other way:

```
$ echo $((16#55))
85
```

With a web-search, I found a script that does the maths and character manipulation to do the conversion, and I could use that as a function, but I'd have thought that bash would already have a built-in base conversion -- does it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378829/convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 86, accepted):

With `bash` (or any shell, provided the `printf` command is available (a standard POSIX command often built in the shells)):

```
printf '%x\n' 85
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
dec=85
hex=$(([##16]dec))
```

That works for bases from 2 to 36 (with `0-9a-z` case insensitive as the digits).

`$(([#16]dev))` (with only one `#`) expands to `16#55` or `0x55` (as a special case for base 16) if the `cbases` option is enabled (also applies to base 8 (`0125` instead of `8#125`) if the `octalzeroes` option is also enabled).

With `ksh93`, you can use:

```
dec=85
base54=${ printf %..54 "$dec"; }
```

Which works for bases from 2 to 64 (with `0-9a-zA-Z@_` as the digits).

With `ksh` and `zsh`, there's also:

```
$ typeset -i34 x=123; echo "$x"
34#3l
```

Though that's limited to bases up to 36 in ksh88, zsh and pdksh and 64 in ksh93.

Note that all those are limited to the size of the `long` integers on your system (`int`'s with some shells). For anything bigger, you can use `bc` or `dc`.

```
$ echo 'obase=16; 9999999999999999999999' | bc
21E19E0C9BAB23FFFFF
$ echo '16o 9999999999999999999999 p' | dc
21E19E0C9BAB23FFFFF
```

With supported bases ranging from 2 to some number required by POSIX to be at least as high as 99. For bases greater than 16, digits greater than 9 are represented as space-separated 0-padded decimal numbers.

```
$ echo 'obase=30; 123456' | bc
 04 17 05 06
```

Or same with `dc` (`bc` used to be (and still is on some systems) a wrapper around `dc`):

```
$ echo 30o123456p | dc
 04 17 05 06
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. (And embarrassingly simple.)

Comment: What if you want to do an arbitrary base like you can specify with `#`?

Comment: @flarn2006. With `bash` builtins, you can _input_ numbers in any base, but not output in any base other than 8, 10 and 16. For other bases, you'd need another shell like `zsh` or `ksh` or use `bc/dc`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Really? That's kind of weird. It almost seems like they were too lazy to program in a syntax for it or something; there's no way the idea of outputting in any base didn't cross their minds if they implemented inputting.

Comment: `alias hex="printf '%x\n'"`

Comment: For a **fixed length**: `printf '%.[LENGTH]X\n' "[NUMBER]"`

Answer (score 13):

Use printf:

```
$ printf "%d %x\n" $((16#55)) $((10#85))
85 55
```

To assign the value to a variable use command substitution:

```
$ x=$( printf "%x" 85 ) ; echo $x
55
```

Comment: Or, use the `-v` option for the builtin printf: `printf -v foo "%d" $((16#BEEF)); echo $foo`

Comment: @Glenn Using non-standard options (like `-v`) is unnecessary here; I'd avoid it.

Comment: `-v` would avoid the fork and pipe (in bash, not ksh93 which wouldn't fork here as `printf` is builtin). Note that `$((16#55))` is not standard either.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, wait a minute. Are you saying that ksh93 does not fork for `x=$(some_builtin)` ?

Comment: @Stephane That's correct. Though, the `#` numeric base indicator is at least supported by all the prominent shells. And for the hex-conversion in this case it's not necessary, as shown in my answer: `x=$( printf "%x" 85 )`

Comment: @glennjackman, yes, it only forks for executing external commands.

Comment: @Glenn, yes ksh has a lot optimization built in, that'a why it's often a magnitue faster than bash.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in Arithmetic Expansion substitution present in all POSIX compliant shells - which is pretty much universal these days.

```
$ echo $((0xbc))
188
```

and

```
$ hex=dead
$ dec=$((0x$hex))
$ echo $dec
57005
```

CAUTION: Particularly in the last example the expansion could cause unexpected results - the hex digits in the variable 'hex' have to form a legal hex constant, otherwise potentially obscure error messages happen.
e.g. if 'hex' were '0xdead', the arithmetic expansion would become 0x0xdead, which is not interpretable as a constant. Of course, in that case the arithmetic expansion $(($hex)) would do the trick. It is left as an exercise for the reader to create the simple substring processing pattern matching  that would remove an optional '0x' prefix.

Comment: You're doing the exact same thing the OP did in his example; he's looking for the *reverse* operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```
$ velour -n 'print n_baseconv(15, 10, 16)'
F
```

Or:

```
$ velour -n 'print n_baseconv(ARGV[1], 10, 16)' 15
F
```